# Define method WPF user control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have this User control:
I added this user control to my `Winforms` application (simple BusyIndicator)

```
UserControl x:Class="Stackoverflow.MyBusyIndicator"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:xctk="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <xctk:BusyIndicator x:Name="busyIndicator" IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}"  />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And all i want is define `Method` that i can access from c# code in order to stop this indicator.

Comment: <xctk:BusyIndicator `x:Name="mBusyIndicator"` IsBusy="True" /> .. Now access this object from code behind to control its behavior...

Comment: I try to put it in the middle of my UserControl and there is errors, in what location i need to put it (i am not familiar with WPF)

Comment: just replace above line....

Comment: i cannot access this from code, i need to define method

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do this in the code behind?

```
public partial class MyBusyIndicator : UserControl
{
    public void ToggleIndicator(bool isBusy)
    {
        // Just an example, in reality you will want to access the BusyIndicator object.
        this.IsBusy = isBusy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why i need partial class MyBusyIndicator : UserControl ? where i need to define ToggleIndicator ? this.IsBusy not exist

Comment: You already have a partial class MyBusyIndicator, I took this from your example? And the code behind is where you would declare a method.

Comment: where i need to declare this method ? and where to declare this class ?

Comment: The class should already exist? Did you create the example XAML? Simply right click on MyBusyIndicator.xaml within VisualStudio and select View Code to modify the existing MyBusyIndicator.xaml.cs

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<UserControl x:Class="Stackoverflow.MyBusyIndicator"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     xmlns:xctk="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <xctk:BusyIndicator x:Name="myBusyIndicator" IsBusy="True" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code Bahind :

```
namespace Stackoverflow
{
   using System;
   using System.Windows;
   using System.Windows.Controls;

   public partial class MyBusyIndicator : UserControl
   {
      public MyBusyIndicator()
      {
         this.InitializeComponent();
      }
      public void ShowIndicator(bool isBusy)
      {
         this.myBusyIndicator.IsBusy = isBusy;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: after this. i don't have the controller name (myBusyIndicator) where i need to put public partial class MyBusyIndicator : UserControl ?

Comment: but i don't understand what this partial class MyBusyIndicator : UserControl class i need to create this as new class in my solution ?

Comment: In this case, Partial class contains all internal XAML coding like `InitializeComponent()` method that you see in above example...

Comment: Ok now i can see but this still continue after set UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();
            uc1.ToggleIndicator(false); - i did it from code in main form

Comment: You have to use `Window` Or `Form` for BusyIndicator parents to your main form. Try googling it you will get everything...

Comment: What do u mean use Window Or Form ?

Answer (score 0):

Your XAML code is fine, now just create a Dependency Property and call it "IsBusy", which you then can bind to in your UserControl XAML using a DataBinding (to visually indicate the IsBusy property state),

```
public partial class BusyIndicator : UserControl
{
    public BusyIndicator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsBusyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsBusyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBusyProperty =  
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsBusy", typeof(bool), typeof(BusyIndicator), 
    new PropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to access it through code-behind first provide a name attribute to the BusyIndicator control through Xaml first: 
 `<xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="True" x:Name="busyIndicator" />`

In your code behind create a method as below:

```
void SetIndicator(bool isBusy)
{
    this.busyIndicator.IsBusy = isBusy;
}
```

If you are using MVVM bind your control's IsBusyProperty `IsBusy={Binding IsBusy}`

`<xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy={Binding IsBusy} />`

And in your viewmodel define IsBusy property and create method as below:

```
void SetIndicator(bool isBusy)
{
    IsBusy = isBusy;
}
```

So next time you want to set is as True call SetIndicator(true) or if you want to set it as false call SetIndicator(false).

Comment: This line: <xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy={Binding IsBusy} /> is with errors: Error 2 ''{' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''.

Comment: I am using it from main form, i dont know what is MVVM

Comment: IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}" should fix it

Comment: If you are using it through main form or code behind as in my previous post and as other posters have mentioned, you will have to name your control. This will allow you to access the IsBusy property of the control from code behind.

Comment: Now it stop but                 UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();
                uc1.SetIndicator(true); not cause this to show again

Comment: Why are you creating a new instance of the UserControl? You should be accessing the instance of the control which is already displayed.

Comment: Check here [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0f7a28a4-c85c-4878-84d4-4a32b587a8de/how-do-i-access-xmal-user-control-properties-from-the-main-windows-code-behind?forum=wpf)

You will have to name the usercontrol in your main form and access it as any other control from there. Then you can access all the child controls and properties of the UserControl from within the Main form. Hope this helps.

Comment: See my update, my control have a name so i try BusyIndicator. and still i cannot reach my method SetIndicator